# Why are all analytic functions equivalent to their Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, analyticity

"A function is analytic if and only if its Taylor series about $x_0$ converges to the function in some neighborhood for every $x_0$ in its domain."

Clearly if its Taylor series converges to $f$ then the function is analytic, but why is the converse true?

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts.

Comment: Also, I asked a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810594/a-question-concerning-the-definition-of-analytic-functions) a while ago that still has me pondering.

Comment: What is your definition of analytic function?

Comment: A function $f$ is analytic on an open set $D$ of the real line if for any $x_0∈D$ one can write

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ b_n(x-x_0)^n.$$

for coefficients $b_i∈ℝ$ and the series is convergent to $f(x)$ on a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: It seems to me that it is just a restatement of the definition.

Comment: @arkeet: It is not (immediately) clear that the $b_n$ are the Taylor coefficients for $f$.

Comment: If the function is given by some power series around $x_0$, you can differentiate it $n$ times and evaluate at $x_0$ to conclude a posteriori that it must be a Taylor series by checking the values of the $b_n$ you get by doing that.

Comment: I suggest you get an introductory text on complex analysis. For example Complex Calculus by Ahlfors.